# Tensorflow graph fetch all consts in a scope

Tags: tensorflow, graph

I create a graph and now I want to fetch their ops, how can I do this?

```
g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default():
    # Define inputs
    with tf.name_scope("inputs"):
        a = tf.constant(2, tf.int32, name="a")
        b = tf.constant(3, tf.int32, name="b")

    # Ops
    with tf.name_scope("ops"):
        c = tf.multiply(a, b, name="c")
        d = tf.add(a, b, name="d")
        e = tf.subtract(c, d, name="e")

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

_c, _d, _e = ... <-- (I need some code here!)
```

Can you show me document links about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sess = tf.Session(graph=g)

_c, _d, _e = sess.run([c, d, e])
print("c =", _c)
print("d =", _d)
print("e =", _e)
```

This will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

[Get_Operations()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operations) will do the job

```
g = tf.Graph()
...

for ops in g.get_operations():
    print(ops)
```